printf causes a segmentation fault when used inside a thread created by clone()
I am trying to use printf inside a thread that is generated by clone(). This is producing a segmentation fault. However, if I instead use std::cout in the same thread, the program runs as expected.
The environment is aarch64 GNU/Linux. Here is the program:
#include <chrono>
#include <csignal>
#include <cstddef>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

#define STACK_SIZE 65536

void sig_handler(int) { exit(0); }

// entry function for clone(..)
int clone_func(void *) {
  for (;;) {
    {

      // segmentation fault. why?
      printf("Child thread: PID = %d\n", getpid());

      // OK
      std::cout << "Child thread" << getpid() << std::endl;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  }
}

pid_t child_pid;
pid_t parent_pid;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  std::signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

  // Stack for the new thread
  char *stack;

  // Top of the stack
  char *stackTop;
  pid_t pid;

  // Allocate memory for the stack
  stack = (char *)malloc(STACK_SIZE);
  if (stack == NULL) {
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Calculate the top of the stack
  stackTop = stack + STACK_SIZE;

  pid = clone(clone_func, stackTop,
              CLONE_VM | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_FS | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_THREAD |
                  CLONE_SETTLS | CLONE_PARENT_SETTID | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID |
                  CLONE_SYSVSEM,
              &parent_pid, NULL, &child_pid);
  if (pid == -1) {
    perror("clone");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // wait for signals
  pause();
}

Can anyone explain this behavior?
---eidt----
After many tests, i found that the problem is caused by the CLONE_SETTLS  flag, which does:
The TLS (Thread Local Storage) descriptor is set to tls.
since i pass NULL for the tls parameter, it's very likely that printf's buffer is also reset to nullptr, leading the segmentation fault error.
Removing of  CLONE_SETTLS  in clone(..) stops segmentation fault.
Finally, this post is not the same as mine, and it does not solve my question:
segfault with clone() and printf

You ask a C++ question...but most of your code is still mostly "C"  style coding ... and you clone processes not threads. E.g.  stack = (char *)malloc(STACK_SIZE); -> std;:stack???

@PepijnKramer CLONE_THREAD flag in clone(..) actually returns a thread. C/C++ mixed is because, what i am trying to do is to dig into the implementation details of std::thread, which is based on pthread, which again is based on the clone(..) system call

segfault in printf in that situation can be only from type mismatch or stack being broken
